# How can I grab a pdf file from the files app in SwiftUI and import it into my app on an iPhone with iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I would like to be able to import pdf files from the Files app to my app and not sure how to achieve this.

Is there a FilePicker or something like that which I can use for a similar behavior to the apple Mail app when you add an attachment to an email?  With mail app when you press "add document" it opens a document browser that you can select a file.  I believe this is from iCloud Drive.

Comment: Try [UIDocumentPickerViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentpickerviewcontroller). For a SwiftUI example see [here](https://gist.github.com/MentalN/d4d2647aedd761831eeaf1450c299887)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `.fileImporter` in SwiftUI:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @State private var presentImporter = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Open") {
            presentImporter = true
        }.fileImporter(isPresented: $presentImporter, allowedContentTypes: [.pdf]) { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let url):
                print(url)
                //use `url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()` if you are going to read the data
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Woah, I had no idea this existed. Nice find!

Comment: @jnpdx: About the question topic, let say we have created the QUI of `fileImporter` in our custom way and it is working, how can I get permission to start reading files App to building and rendering my QUI without using fileImporter or other older ways. In other word let say there is no `fileImporter`, and we created our custom View look like the `fileImporter`, how can I start reading data from files App?

Comment: @swiftPunk as far as I know, you can’t. The OS only gives you access to the files explicitly chosen by the user or in the app’s containers (including its iCloud Drive folder), but not an arbitrary list of other files on the system.

Comment: @jnpdx: probably I will ask it as a question to get more information, is it right to say, that apple does not trust us to give direct access to files App, and it must be through a secure way like `fileImporter` that apple would be okay in this case?

Comment: @swiftPunk I would frame it a little differently. It's not that Apple doesn't "trust us" -- it's that the user needs to grant permission to an app for it to open/read files. This is similar to how we can't get location data without getting permission from the user first. By the way, I think the term you're looking for is "GUI" not "QUI"

Comment: @jnpdx: yes, I have always this typing issue, english is not my first language plus I make tons of typo also. So if I understand you correctly, apple could pup a message to screen and ask about permission from user to accessing the files App, theoretically it should be possible!?

Comment: I have used this to successfully grab a pdf url.  But when I try to do something with it I can't and wondering if the file is private.  I'm trying if let pDFDocument = PDFDocument(url: url) ... but it's nil and file starts with file:///private/var/mobile/ etc...

Comment: Probably need to call this on the URL: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurl/1417051-startaccessingsecurityscopedreso

Answer (score 0):

Regarding @jnpdx answer,
don't forgot to add check for accessing files, if you need to read it.
Like

```
            guard url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() else { return }
            defer { url.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource() }
```